# $W^{k,2}(\mathbb{R}^n) \hookrightarrow L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $k,n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $k>\frac{n}{2}$. How can one prove that $u\in W^{k,2}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ may be embedded into $L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Answer (score 2):

We can use Fourier analysis. First, if $u$ is a test function, we can write 
$$u(x)=C\int_{\Bbb R^n}\widehat u(t)e^{itx}(1+|t|^2)^{k/2}(1+|t|^2)^{-k/2}dt.$$
Then using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have 
$$|u(x)|^2\leqslant C^2\lVert u\rVert_{H^k}^2\int_{\Bbb R}(1+|t|^2)^{-k}dt=C^2\lVert u\rVert_{H^k}^2\omega_n^2\int_{\Bbb R}(1+s^2)^{-k}s^{n-1}ds.$$
Then we conclude by density of test functions (using a sequence converging also almost everywhere).